# Simple Buffer Overflow in C

Tags: c, arrays, buffer, overflow

So I am doing an excercise where I am attempting to get the following program to output Welcome to Overflow by changing the relevant variables using a buffer overflow. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int a = 10;
  char c = 'X';
  char array2[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
  char array[4];
  printf("please enter: \n");
  scanf("%s", array);

  printf("c = %c\n", c);
  printf("a = %d\n", a);
  printf("array = %s\n", array);
  printf("array2 = %s\n", array2);
  printf("array[2] = %x\n", *(array + 2));
  printf("array2[3] = %x\n", array2[3]);


  if (c == 'X' && a == 11999 && *(array + 2) == 0x99 - 0x34 && array2[3] == 'X') {
    printf("Welcome to overflow!\n");
  } else {
    printf("This is normal output!\n");
  }
}
```

What I need is for `c == 'X' && a == 11999 && *(array + 2) == 0x99 - 0x34 && array2[3] == 'X'`.
So I have gotten every variable to be what I want it to be except one.
By inputting the following I am able to change them. I input *"XXeXXXXXXXXB"* This changes `array[2]` to be *65*, `array2[3]` to be *X*, `c` to *'X'* but the variable I cannot change is 'a'. By making the *12th* char of input `a` *B* it changes `a` to '66', which is the decimal equivalent of the char 'B'.   If I input a 13th char, variable `a` will then be changed to the decimal equivelent of the char * 257. Since `a` needs to be 11999 I am lost.
I tried dividing 11999 by 257 but it comes out to 46.6 so there is no char with that value, I even tried the char closest to 46.6 which were '.' and '/' but then `a` is too big or too small.

What char or chars can I make the 12th and 13th input in order to change `a` into 11999? Also if you do not want to give me the flat out answer I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: If a is supposed to be 11999, what is that in hex?  And what chars would form that?

Comment: So I did a conversion and found 11999 in hex is 0x2EDF. So when crafting my payload I should do something like echo -e -n 'XXeXXXXXXXX\0x2EDF' > payload?

Comment: 11999 is hex 2EDF. So you had to change the upper byte by '.' but the lower one is a special character (eg. the german 'ß' in CP-1252)

Comment: The code has undefined behavior trying to write non-null terminated char array using `%s`

Comment: Ah so I now see that you split it up like so '2E' and then 'DF' with 2E = '.' and DF = 'ß'. But when I try inputting . and ß as the last 2 chars, a changes into 10470190.

Comment: How many chars in an int?

Comment: `char array2[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};` Do you know what happens when you call `printf` here =>> `printf("array2 = %s\n", array2);` ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is it 4 since a int can hold 32 bits and 1 char is 8  bits?

Comment: Doesn't it just display what array2 currently holds in its 6 spots?

Comment: I am still lost, I feel very close though!

Comment: Add  `printf("&a=%p, &c=%p, array2=%p, array=%p\n", &a, &c, array2, array);` to your output.  The variables are most likely not placed where you expect.

Comment: I tried adding that and now I see what I believe to be the addresses of where the variables are held?

Comment: I am stuck,I am still unsure of how to overwrite 'a' using only 1 char to make it 11999

Comment: int = 4 chars, so 11999 = 00002EDF in hex.

Comment: Alright so I am understanding a little better I think. There are 15 bytes in total (8 bits each). So the first 10 chars I enter fill up array 1 with XXeX, the next 6 I enter fill up array 2 with XXXXXX. The next char I enter will replace variable 'C' with whatever I put in as the 11th char, which is an 'X'. The next on the stack is int 'a' which is 4 bytes or 4 chars. I need to fill it with 00002EDF, or in char form (null null . ß). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: At this point I would like the correct answer and an explanation as to why it is what is, thanks

Comment: Can anyone provide the input and an explanation as to why it is that input? I have been trying this for 16 hours now stuck on this last part.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting exercise. Because you are invoking undefined behavior, there isn't exactly one answer to your question, it has to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis. This attack may not even work on some machines.

First, for this kind of test you should be using printf to see where the data is:

```
printf("a is at %p\n", &a);
printf("array is at %p\n", array);
...
```

This should give you an idea of how many bytes you need to offset. Next determine whether you are working on a little-endian or big-endian system. If you are working on little-endian then 11999 is 0xDF2E0000, if you are using big-endian it is backwards.

So given your program on a little-endian system, assuming all data is in the correct order in memory for it to work, and the integer is 4 bytes, you need the string "--" + (0x99-0x34) + "-...X..X" + 0xDF2E0000

**EDIT:** The reason for this string is as follows:

- first 4 bytes: "--e-" fills in your input array
- Next 6 bytes: "...X..X" fills in array2 and c, with correct placement of X's
- Last 4 bytes: 0xDF2E0000 fills in your int (little endian) with 11999

You can test this by adding:

```
#include <string.h>
char str[] = {16};
sprintf(str, "--%c-...X..X%c%c\0\0", 0x99 - 0x34, 0xDF, 0x2E);
memcpy(array, str, 14);
printf("The string is: \"%s\"", str);
```

In place of your scanf. Obviously you can figure out the characters associated with those values and paste them in, but this is the fastest way to get the correct data.

Of course, this is subjective to change based on system, and the code I have above may not even work on your machine. This is still a very real thing, and a good demonstration of why you should always limit the number of characters you are reading and writing, as well as make sure you use proper ending characters.

If I missed any assumptions/factors above I would appreciate if someone lets me know so I can add them.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your explanation, but I am still struggling. I am really just at wits end. I need to replace the last 4 bytes of data (int a) with 0000DF2E. I cannot for the life of me figure it out. I have tried inputting almost everything.

Comment: @KevinJones are you on a big endian system? You should first try modifying the code I supplied to do what you want.

Comment: I am on little endian

Comment: You should be able to copy/paste my code into yours then, replacing the scanf. You need the number 2EDF0000 because you are on little endian.

Comment: If you add `printf("a: %p, arr: %p\n", &a, array);" which address is higher?

Comment: The following prints      a: 0xbf8e5b2c   arr:0xbf8e5b32 how can i tell which is higher?

Comment: Then you cannot use this attack on this code. Notice how a is before array on the stack, this means that when you write too much into array, it won't bleed into a like you expect, it will bleed into a different part of your stack, which is why you get the exception in the image above. You should look into how memory is laid out before trying choice like this

Comment: As mentioned above, it does seem to be overflowing into a after the 12th character. For example if the 12th character is an 'B' 'a' then becomes 66 or the decimal equivalent of char 'B'

Comment: @KevinJones ah, that was my bad. I assumed the system architecture, something I specifically warn about in my own post. I have updated my code and added a breakdown of the string to my answer.